# How does cassandra scale for a single key read

Tags: cassandra

How does cassandra handle large amount of reads for a single key? Think about a very popular celebrity whose twitter page is hit consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will usually have multiple replicas of each shard. Lets say your replica count is 3. Then reads for a single key can be spread over the nodes hosting those replicas. But that's the limit of the parallelism - adding more nodes to your cluster would not increase the number of replicas and hence the traffic would still have to talk to just those 3 nodes. There's various tricks people use for such cases (e.g. caching in the web server so it doesn't have to keep going back to the database or denormalizing the data so it is spread over more nodes).

Comment: Replica won't really help here since the number of reads for the key is disproportionately larger than other keys. I think you're strategy of handling this at ingress is what would work.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that it does help (e.g. 3 replicas could support 3x the throughput of 1) but that's the limit: you'd never want a cluster with tons of replicas so you can't horizontally scale your way out of the problem. So it helps some but in many circumstances you'll still need other approaches.